# Is there a polygon of world countries from -360 to 360 degrees in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am kind of stuck on how to plot world maps that do not adjust to the map_data provide by the ggplot2 package, which is "world" (from -180 to 180 degrees) and "world2" (from 0 to 360 degrees). For example, if I want to plot from 100°E to 20°E, no polygon provide by ggplot2 is useful. Here is the code of the example:

```
library(ggplot2)

map1 <- map_data('world')
map2 <- map_data('world2')

ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = map1, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  coord_fixed(1.4, xlim = c(100,380))

ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = map2, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  coord_fixed(1.4, xlim = c(100,380))
```

So, are there world maps polygons like those of the example but with a greater range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is scrappy, but why not? You could show a duplicated world so that every region can be shown without going over the edge.

```
library(dplyr)
map1 <- map_data('world')
map2 <- map_data('world') %>% mutate(long = long+360)
map3 <- map_data('world') %>% mutate(long = long+720)


ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = map1, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  geom_polygon(data = map2, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  geom_polygon(data = map3, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  
  coord_fixed(1.4, xlim = c(100,480))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than finding those polygons, you might just clip the longitude boundaries with a coord_quickmap() or coord_sf(). Note that coord_map() will incorrectly group polygon's points unless clipped before the ggplot() call.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_polygon(data = map2, 
               mapping = aes(x = long, 
                             y = lat, 
                             group = group),
               col = 'gray') +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(20,100))
  #coord_quickmap(xlim = c(100,20)) is also an alternative to coord_sf()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"world" and "world2" are two versions of the world map that are implemented in the "maps" package. But that package actually allows you to define a world map with any boundaries, e.g. c(20,380) or c(100,460).

The simplest way is just to use the "wrap" option (which is described in the man page of maps::map). This option is passed to maps::map() (so look in the maps package for full help page)

```
map3 <- map_data('world', wrap=c(20,380))
```

This should give you a nice map for any meridian that you may choose. Note that in this case "wrap" must be be a vector and that the left and right boundaries must be exactly 360 apart.